# Webapp couldn't find jars located in WEB-INF/lib folder

Tags: java, tomcat

On production Tomcat server my webapp couldn't find jars located in WEB-INF/lib folder. In development eviorment all works fine.

Stack Trace

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not initialize class util.HibernateUtil
    web.Engine.service(Engine.java:58)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class util.HibernateUtil
    web.Engine.service(Engine.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5 logs.
```

**Development Config**
Tomcat 5.5
OS X 10.6
Eclipse

**Production Config**
Tomcat 5.5
Linux Debian

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Tomcat that ships with Debian distros has a very restrictive Java security manager. My guess is that you're using the packaged version and that it is forbidding something. The "*something*" is very likely available in the logs as mentioned in the last line of the trace you posted:

> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5 logs.

You'll have to ease the restrictions (check `/etc/tomcat5.5/policy.d`) or to turn it off. Talk with your administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen something very similar with a jar requiring a class from another jar and *that* jar was not on the classpath.

Have a look at the root cause of the stack trace in the Tomcat log.  That will most likely reveal what is wrong.